# Getting 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable while collecting coordinates field from Twitter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweepy

Ok, so I have a cod that collects data from twitter but I get an error when I include the coordinates field. The code runs a few time but I get this error.

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time
import string
import json
import re

ckey ='mykey'
csecret ='mykey'
atoken = 'mykey'
asecret = 'mykey'

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            jsonData=json.loads(data)
            geo_lat=jsonData['geo']['coordinates'][0] // field that get error
            geo_long=jsonData['geo']['coordinates'][1] // field that get erro
            savethis=+str(geo_lat)+', '+str(geo_long)          
            print unicode(savethis).encode("utf-8")
            return True
        except BaseException, e:
             print 'Falied on data,',str(e)
             time.sleep(5)
        def on_error(self, status):
            print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
#twitterStream.filter(locations=[-78,15,-70,18 ])
twitterStream.filter(locations=[-74,40,-73,41])
```

**Error** -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Kevonia/Dropbox/Major Project/Python Workspace/database&filerwithbugs.py", line 46, in on_data
geo_lat=jsonData['geo']['coordinates'][0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please post the complete error traceback.

Comment: You should test if the jsonData has the key geo and after that test if there is coordinates field. Sometimes json from twitter can not have the full information. And also like @thefourtheye  said you should post the error message.

Comment: Please, make these tests before the assignment of geo_lat, and post the output of the prints:

     if ("geo" in jsonData.keys()):
        print "There is geo"
        if ("coordinates" in jsonData["geo"].keys()):
           print "There is coordinates", json["geo"]["coordinates"]

Comment: it works  for a while then i get this error :

Comment: if ("coordinates" in jsonData["geo"].keys()): print "There is coordinates", jsonData["geo"]["coordinates"]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: and this when i removed the .key()

Comment: if ("coordinates" in jsonData["geo"]): print "There is coordinates", jsonData["geo"]["coordinates"]
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: please, don't put the relevant to your question info in the comments, [update your question instead](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22264289/edit)

Answer (score 0):

either `jsonData` or `jsonData['geo']` or `jsonData['geo']['coordinates']` is set to `null` in the json text that translates to `None` in Python.

```
>>> None['whatever']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```